# SAS keep blanks in variables

Tags: string, sas

i have this data set with 1 observation,

the length of information is $100

```
 information
  Susan
 Peter
 Johny
```

if i want substring 6

x=substr(information,1,6)

i need the lefts and right blanks because i'll concatenate it with other string,

example:

```
    stringConcat1 SusanStringConcat2
    stringConcat1Peter StringConcat2
    stringConcat1Jonhny StringConcat2
```

i know that if i have a observation with a length it fill with blanks but this length can be variable when i use a loop, how can i do it? because SAS trim the blanks

i tried the function subpad(information,1,6) but is the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If concatenating the variables together is your goal, here is some code that uses the [CAT](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002257060.htm) function which might help you get started

```
data have;
 Length Var $20;
 Input Var $;
 datalines;
information
Susan
Peter
Johny 
;

Data need;
 Length Concat $5000;
 Retain Concat;
 Set have end=last;

 if _n_=1 then Concat=strip(Var);
 else  Concat=cat(strip(concat),", ",strip(var));

 if last then do;
  put Concat=;
  call symputx('Concat',concat);
 end;
Run;
%Put CONCAT: &concat;
```